# Getting "Unable to extract the User from the SOAP Header" exception

Tags: c#, soap

Here while making request to web service  I am Getting the  exception as **FaultExceptionwas un handled**  with the message as **Unable to extract the User from the SOAP Header**
My code is as below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Request.ServicesExternalClient se = new Request.ServicesExternalClient();
            se.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName";
            se.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password1";
            BindingElementCollection elements =  se.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
            elements.Add(SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameForSslBindingElement());
            System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("--url--");
            se.Endpoint.ListenUri = uri;        
            StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
            xml.Append(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>");
                 xml.Append(@"<NewInvoiceRequest >");
                 xml.Append(@"<tracingLevel>OFF</tracingLevel>");
                 '
                 '
                 '
                 '
                 '
                 '
                 '
                 xml.Append(@"</NewInvoiceRequest>");      
                Request.NewInvoiceRequest newInvRequest = new Request.NewInvoiceRequest();             
                Request.Invoice inv = new Request.Invoice();
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request.NewInvoiceRequest));
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);                
                    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml.ToString()))
                    {                    
                            newInvRequest = (Request.NewInvoiceRequest)s.Deserialize(sr);
                    }         
                }

                Request.NewInvoiceResponse res = se.createNewInvoice(newInvRequest);
        }
```